# Python List of charts in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a program which takes DataFrame and writes it into excel as chart(using xlsxwriter and pandas libraries). For example, I wrote column-stacked-chart into excel.

What I want now is to add line chart to that excel chart which was created before. This isn't problem if I write them in the same function, but first chart is already created and I don't have that object in another code. I want to combine them, so I need to get list of charts in excel to take first one, create second and combine them.